# Converting predictions to labels with threshold

Tags: python, numpy

Assuming I have the following numpy array

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0.2, 0.8], [0.99, 0.01], [0.08, 0.92]])
arr
Out[57]: 
array([[0.2 , 0.8 ],
       [0.99, 0.01],
       [0.08, 0.92]])
```

If I'd like to convert this output to "classes" (or the index of greatest value in each row) I'd simply use:

```
arr.argmax(axis=1)
Out[58]: array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

Problem is, I want to restrict a certain theshold. For the example let's use **0.9**. So every row that doesn't meet with the threshold constraint will return the label -1.

Out put for the above example will then be `[-1, 0, 1]` (because neither 0.8 nor 0.2 are greater than 0.9).

What is the most pythonic way to do it? hopefully (but not a must), using `numpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
m = arr > 0.9
np.where(m.any(axis=1), m.argmax(axis=1), -1)
array([-1,  0,  1])
```

**Details**

`(arr > 0.9)` returns an `ndarray` with the same shape indicating where the condition is met:

```
array([[False, False],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]])
```

`m.argmax(axis=1)` returns where `m` is `True`:

```
array([0, 0, 1])
```

`np.where` will return `m.argmax(axis=1)` for those rows which satisfy `m.any(axis=1)`, thus where at least one element is greater than the threshold. Here `m.any(axis=1)` gives:

```
array([False,  True,  True])
```

Otherwise `np.where` will return `-1`

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks yatu.